# babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate breaks only one single service injection with AngularJS ^1.8.0 and Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, babeljs

We are developing an AngularJS application with ES6 modules. We're using webpack and babel to transform and package our code, with the `babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate` plugin used to automatically handle DI.

The issue arises on a single service, let's call it `MainController`. Its dependencies are `$log`, `$scope`, `$uibModal`, and `MainApi`, which is a custom service.

Decorating this exported function with `/* @ngAnnotate */` results with the following:

```js
var MainController = function ($log, $scope, $uibModal, _MainApi) { /*...*/ }
// -----------------------------------------------------^ Why the underscore?
MainController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', '$uibModal', '_MainApi'];
// -------------------------------------------------------^ Why the underscore?
export default MainController;
```

As you can see, instead of `MainApi` being injected, it is transformed into `_MainApi`.
Other services in other parts of the code also rely on `MainApi`, and it is properly injected into those services.

Removing the `/* @ngInject */` "decorator" also removes the `$inject` part of the code, which, naturally, does not work either.

What causes that single injection argument to get prefixed and how do we prevent that from happening? Again, literally every single other DI component is injected properly and works, except for this one instance.

Here is our `.babelrc`

```json
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
                }
            }
        ],
        ["@babel/preset-react"]
    ],
    "plugins": [["angularjs-annotate", { "explicitOnly": true }]]
}
```

And webpack config

```js
const path = require('path');

var pluginCopy = require('./webpack/plugin-copy-docker');
var loadEnv = require('./webpack/load-env');
var rules = require('./webpack/module-rules');
var PACKAGE = require('./package.json');
var version = PACKAGE.version;
var zipPlugin = require('webpack-zip-files-plugin');

module.exports = function ( env) {
    var config = loadEnv( env.ENV);
    var configFilename = '__config.php';

    return {
        mode: config['ENV_MODE'],
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve('app/proto', 'app.js'),
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/www'),
        },
        module: {
            rules: rules,
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            pluginCopy(configFilename),
            new zipPlugin({
                entries: [
                    { src: path.join(__dirname, './dist'), dist: './' },
                ],
                output: path.join(__dirname, './proto-docker-v'+version),
                format: 'zip',
            })
        ],
    };
};
```

Here are the rules

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports =  [
    {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.html$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'html-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    },
    {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff',
    },
    {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    },
    {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['svg-inline-loader'],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `@babel/plugin-transform-function-name` plugin, which transforms function names, and occasionally prefixes existing variable names with underscores. See this GitHub discussion for more details: https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/12067

This can be solved by excluding the plugin:

```
{
   "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
         "exclude": ["transform-function-name"]
      }]
   ]
}
```